# Mobilevision facetracker in videochat (quickblox)

Tags: android, google-vision, quickblox-android

Hello I use quickblox API for videocall and I am trying to implement google mobile vision API i have no errors but not overlays are shown and nothing happens in the video call can you please help me with that .

Comment: It will be helpful if you put some code of your POC.

Comment: In fact it's a whole project I implemented the quickblox api which has it's own CameraSource for videocall and mobile vision works with : 
'mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder()' 
which is not recognised by quickblox , so is there any way to go around and track which is shown on the screen or the video stream itself